# Calculating boundary length of a Voronoi cell

Tags: algorithm, voronoi

What is the most efficient algorithm to calculate the boundary of a Voronoi cell?
To be more specific, say we have a list of points (in 2 dimensions to simplify the problem): P1, P2, P3.. Pn
Now if I want to just find the length of the boundary of the Voronoi cell of a random point, say Pi, which is shared with another neighboring point Pj, is there an efficient algorithm for this?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you represent your Voronoi diagram. Bitmap?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to compute the Voronoi diagram. That is expensive. I think the computation of the length of the shared boundary can be done without computing the whole Voronoi diagram. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: so you are going to calc the boundary length of only a certain cell, not of every cell?

Comment: Yes, I wanted the boundaries' length of a certain cell which are shared with its neighbors.

Comment: so you want the *perimeter* of a cell?

Comment: Not exactly. I want a list consisting of lengths of the boundaries, which are shared by the cell with its neighbors (the sum of which, would be its perimeter).

Comment: OK, I see. Why do you think it's expensive to compute the whole diagram? You could do it at a complexity of `O(NlogN)`, and then compute the length list easily. Do you want an algorithm with less complexity or something else?

Comment: One reason to not compute the Vornoi diagram is that although it is of complexity of O(nlogn) in 2 dimensions, it's complexity goes worse as the dimensions increase. For example, in 100 dimensions, the complexity would be O(n^50). Intuitively it seems that the computing boundary of a single cell should be much less, but I am not sure. I would also be okay if the boundary calculation is not exact. For example, we can do sampling of points. But how to sample points close to the boundary is not so clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I now have a solution for this problem, but I am not sure if it is efficient enough for many dimensions. Let me re-define the problem.

Problem: Say our list of points is {P1, P2, P3, . . .Pk, X} and our query point is X; ie we are interested in finding the hypervolume of the facet which is shared (in 2 dimensions the length of shared edge) between Voronoi cell of Pi and Voronoi cell of X.

Solution:

1. We find a set of points CC = {T1, T2, T3, . . .Tk-1} which are circumcentres of points {Pi,X,Pj}, where j<>i and 1<=j<=k. This can be done in O(k)
2. From the set CC, we can remove points which do not lie within the Voronoi cell of X. This can be done in O(k^2) and without computing any Voronoi diagram.
3. The rest of the points left in the set CC will completely define the bounding facet which is shared between Voronoi cell of Pi and Voronoi cell of X. In two dimensions, we will be left with only two points (end points of the shared edge) in the set CC, from which we can find the length easily.
4. Now, since we have our bounding facet defined, we can find an approximate volume of this facet easily in polynomial time.

Comment: This is not an efficient solution because as the dimensions increase, the complexity to calculate the circumcenters increases.